# Stop procedure if condition is not met using a global variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA:

```
Stop_Continue As Boolean

Sub Main_Procedure()
    If Stop_Continue = False Then
        Call Insert_Value
    Else
        MsgBox ("Insert values failed.")
    End If
End Sub

Sub Check()
    If Sheet1.Range("A1") = 40 _
      And Sheet1.Range("B1") = 60 _
      And Sheet1.Range("C1") = 90 Then
        Stop_Continue = False
    Else
        Stop_Continue = True
    End If
End Sub

Sub Insert_Value()
    Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = 100
End Sub
```

The `Main_Procedure` triggers the `Check` and if the check is positive the procedure should continue with `Insert_Value`. If not it should stop and give the message `"Insert values failed"`. 
I wan to use the boolean variable `Stop_Continue` to store the result of the `Check` and use it in the `Main_Procedure` to decide if it should continue or not.

However, somehow this code is not working because it inserts the `100` into Cell `A2` no matter if the conditions in `Check` are met or not.

Do you know what I have to change in my code to make it work?

Comment: Let's be sure you got the logic, right: if A1 = 40 AND B1 =60 AND C1 = 90, THEN A2=100, right?

Comment: Yes, so if one of them is not met, let's say in A1 the value is 30 the procedure should stop and A2 should remain emtpy.

Comment: OK that's fine. Try my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your variable as `Public`:

```
Public Stop_Continue As Boolean
```

---

```
Sub Main_Procedure()
Call Check
If Stop_Continue = False Then
    Call Insert_Value
Else
    MsgBox ("Insert values failed.")
End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Check()
If Sheet1.Range("A1") = 40 _
    And Sheet1.Range("B1") = 60 _
    And Sheet1.Range("C1") = 90 Then
    Stop_Continue = False
Else
    Stop_Continue = True
End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Insert_Value()
Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = 100
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when the value in A1 is 30 it still continues and inserts the 100 into A2 although it should stop because the condition A1=40 is not met.

Comment: @Michi, that's not possible because I set up example data and it worked. Delete the module and insert the code into a new module.

Comment: I found the issue. I did not use the code in the module. I used it in ThisWorkbook. Thanks for the hint with the "module". Actually, what is the reason why it only runs in the module and not in ThisWorkbook?

Comment: @Michi, I am glad it worked for you. You can upvote as well :). I think sometimes the VBA project needs refresh. If you were to delete the Module code, and clear your ThisWorkbook and paste the code again, it would work. It's weird, but I have had it happen before.

Comment: After a few trials I came to the conclusion that it is only working if the Public Stop_Continue As Boolean is stored in the module. The rest of the code can be in ThisWorkbook. OR if the Public Stop_Continue As Boolean is in the first line of code in ThisWorkbook so there should not be any other code before the public variable.

Answer (score 2):

**Change your Main Procedure to this:**

```
Sub Main_Procedure()

Call Check

If Stop_Continue = False Then
Call Insert_Value
Else
MsgBox ("Insert values failed.")
End If
End Sub
```

You are not calling Check, that is Check is not being Executed.

Also try running your code Using `F8` to see What is happening at every Step

Comment: Hi Mikku, thanks for your answer but I still have the same issue.

Comment: @Michi .. i think then issue is with your If Condition. Check that.

Comment: @Mikku: It was not working because I used the VBA unter ThisWorkbook and not in the "Module". Upvotes for your answer.